# A question about the Rehabilitation of Offenders Act. UK

Tags: data-protection

Suppose I get an offer to study a PhD, and in the application procedure I was not asked about a criminal record at all. According to the rehabilitation of offenders, I can choose to withhold my criminal record. If I am under the care of a psychiatrist in a psychiatric ward, can my psychiatrist tell my PhD supervisor about my criminal record?

I seem to think that this is a breach of data protection. Can someone clarify this for me?